# How to find the same spec AMI in different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

as title, while I create CFN template, I always check EC2 console for AMI id in different regions.

these ids belong to the same spec image, 
ex: all of them are "ubuntu 12.04 64 bit", but in various regions

is there any quick method to check this messages?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no method for identifying matching AMIs across different regions.

Some background...

An **Amazon Machine Image (AMI)** contains a disk image that is used to boot an Amazon EC2 instance. It is created by using the **Create Image** command on an existing Amazon EC2 instance, and can also be created from an EBS Snapshot (Linux only).

**Each AMI receives a unique ID** in the form `ami-1234abcd`.

**AMIs exist in only one AWS region.** When an AMI is copied between regions, it receives a new AMI ID. This means that the "same" image will appear with a different AMI ID in each region.

When an AMI is copied between regions, it will retain its name and description, but this is not necessarily unique, so it cannot be used to definitively match AMIs between regions.

AMI creators will often supply a list of matching AMI IDs across regions, for example: [Amazon Linux AMI IDs](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/)

Comment: Thank you, John! at least now I know the sharing list maybe exist :)